# How to pass a value from one row to the next one in pandas + python and use it to calculate the same following value recursively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

This is my desired output:

[image]

I am trying to calculate the column `df[Value]` and `df[Value_Compensed]`. However, to do that, I need to consider  the previous value of the row `df[Value_Compensed]`. In terms of my table:

- The first row all the values are 0
- The following rows: `df[Remained] = previous df[Value_compensed]`. Then `df[Value] = df[Initial_value] + df[Remained]`. Then `df[Value_Compensed] = df[Value] - df[Compensation]`

...And So on...

I am struggling to pass the value of Value_Compensed from one row to the next, I tried with the function shift() but as you can see in the following image the values in `df[Value_Compensed]` are not correct due to it is not a static value and also it also changes after each row it did not work. Any Idea??

[image]

Thanks.

Manuel.

Comment: What does the original df look like?

Comment: It is the same table but only with the columns Compensation and initial_Value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to create your customised operations. I've made a dummy dataset as you didn't provide the initial dataframe.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (8, 5)),
                  columns=['compensation', 'initial_value',
                           'remained', 'value', 'value_compensed'],)
df.loc[0] = 0,0,0,0,0

>>> print(df)
   compensation  initial_value  remained  value  value_compensed
0             0              0         0      0                0
1             2              9         1      9                7
2             1              4         9      8                3
3             3              4         5      7                6
4             3              2         5      5                6
5             9              1         5      2                4
6             4              5         9      8                2
7             1              6         9      6                8
```

Use apply (`axis=1`) to do row-wise iteration, where you use the initial dataframe as an argument, from which you can then get the previous row `x.name-1` and do your calculations. Not sure if I fully understood the intended result, but you can adjust the individual calculations of the different columns in the function.

```
def f(x, data):
    if x.name == 0:
        return [0,]*data.shape[1]
    else:
        x_remained = data.loc[x.name-1]['value_compensed']
        x_value = data.loc[x.name-1]['initial_value'] + x_remained
        x_compensed = x_value - x['compensation']

        return [x['compensation'], x['initial_value'], x_remained, \
               x_value, x_compensed]

adj = df.apply(f, args=(df,), axis=1)
adj = pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip_longest(*adj.values), index=df.columns).T

>>> print(adj)
   compensation  initial_value  remained  value  value_compensed
0             0              0         0      0                0
1             5              9         0      0               -5
2             5              7         4     13                8
3             7              9         1      8                1
4             6              6         5     14                8
5             4              9         6     12                8
6             2              4         2     11                9
7             9              2         6     10                1
```